# Access files of root very slow at linux

Tags: linux, operating-system, root

I login in system with normal user， it is ok to execute the command like: `echo hello`, `cat ~/.bashrc`. But when I execute command to access files of root, ex: `su`, `cat /proc/uptime`, it run very slow. what is the problem? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your /etc/hosts file. sometimes it can cause this delay. try to put following on your /etc/hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
x.x.x.x  your-remoteserver
```

if /etc/hosts file is correct then check /etc/pam.d/system-auth.

Answer (score 0):

use `strace` and check were you get most time leak. I cannot help you without enough logs.